# Rspec and FactoryGirl: SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a problem with FactoryGirl:

Here is my 2 factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    ...
    after(:build) do |task|
      question = FactoryGirl.create(:question)
      task.questions = [question]
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    association :task, factory: :task
    ...
  end
end
```

Question factory creates Task, Task factory creates Question, etc. So, I have a message: "SystemStackError: stack level too deep".

How can I solve this problem without breaking the associations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting a "stack level too deep" error because you're defining both factories in terms of each other. You don't need the `association :task, factory: task` line in the `question` factory -- the association will be set when you create a task.

Try this for your `task` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    ...
    questions { [ FactoryGirl.create(:question) ] }
  end
end
```

Comment: What if I want to instantiate a `question` object like `create(:question)` (it should have an associated `task`)?

Comment: Create a task and then use `task.questions.first` to get the question.

Comment: It looks weird. It's more obvious to create a `question` directly instead of creating `task`.

Comment: Well then create a question with a normal task association on it, and in your `task` factory define a `task_with_questions` factory with `task` as its parent, and `after(:create) { |t| FactoryGirl.create(:question, task: t) }`. Then you get both.